# How to filter event flow by category?

Tags: google-analytics

I have two categories for an event. one for the website and the other for a javascript app.

I want to know what's happening in the app and don't want to see the website events like page views etc.

Is this possible?

Also, I found that my own javascript app sends traffic to a intermediary page and it shows up. How do I prevent this from happening? I want to make sure that a particular page on my website does not get counted towards pageview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom segment that includes users that had a specific event category during their session:

[image: event category filter]

When you reach the events flow report, use that one and the data will be filtered accordingly.

As for ignoring that page, you can exclude it from the reports using a filter. Go to admin-->filters and create a filter like the following:

[image: filter]

The "Filter Pattern" require a regex expressions. You can use:

```
.*{the specific URL without the http://www.}
```

If you have changing parameters at the end of the URL you can add `.*` at the end of the above expression. It will make sure that everything after this URL will be excluded as well.